# Split string into row

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I am using MySQL.

I have a table named "**class**", the "**class**" table has three columns `name` , `year` and `class_code` like following:

**Class** table:

[image]

Now I would like to use the above table to create a new table named "**temp**", which contains `class_code` and `value` columns.

The rule is that each string value in each column field of a row of the above "**class**"  table will be split into words, and each word will be inserted to the "**temp**" table as `value` column of a **temp** table record like following:

**temp** table:

[image]

I am using MySQL.

Is it possible to generate the "**temp**" table purely by using SQL statement and how?

That's :

```
CREATE TABLE temp;

ALTER TABLE temp DISABLE KEYS;

INSERT INTO ...(how to split the string value of each field in "class" table and insert to "temp" table??? )
```

**P.S.:**
 I used a simple equal length string as a value, but the actually case has very **random** length string, and the number of words in each string is **random** also.

Comment: Horrifying table design.  If you have the option, store the TEMP and generate the CLASS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to do a split on a sql table column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087885/how-to-do-a-split-on-a-sql-table-column)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a function for string splitting in MySql as

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

And use it to split the values and do the assigning the splitted values and inserting in to table in a SP.For more information refer to the [MySQL Split String](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

Comment: If I do not want to use "pos INT" at all, I prefer a function return all the substrings, how to refactor the above function definition?

Comment: @Mellon, refer to the link I provide in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,  1, 4) as field, class_code FROM old_table
UNION
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,  6, 4) as field, class_code FROM old_table
UNION
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 11, 4) as field, class_code FROM old_table
UNION
SELECT SUBSTRING(year,  1, 4) as field, class_code FROM old_table
UNION
SELECT SUBSTRING(year,  6, 4) as field, class_code FROM old_table
```

Comment: Hi, My post just use a simple equal length string as a value, but the actually case has very random length string, so , I think your answer is not that good.

Comment: @mellon, you should have stated that in the question. Is the number of items after value split constant?

Comment: No, it is not constant either.

Comment: @mellon, in this case the task is not that simple in plain SQL. I would split in PHP or Python and insert in a new table.