# SQL query - split a string in a field, expand rows so they contain substrings

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to do a split on a sql table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087885/how-to-do-a-split-on-a-sql-table-column)

I have a following MySQL table

```
(ID,my_string)
(1,"substrA,substrB,substrC")  
(2,"substrD,substrE")
...
```

is there some statment that would allow
to split string into the individual substrings(separated by comma) and merge them with the corresponding ID?

like

```
(ID,substring)
(1,substrA)
(1,substrB)
(1,substrC) 
(2,substrD)
(2,substrE)  
...
```

thank you for advice in advance

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such built-in function in mysql

Answer (score 0):

check it:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: I mean the question is is it possible to split string and connect resulting vector of values to ID without having to do this rowwise?

Comment: I mean the question is is it possible to split string and connect resulting vector of substrings to ID without having to do this rowwise. Or more general is it possible for each row (but by application of query to the full table) to  generate some vector of values,repeat row n-times(n=length of the vector of values for the respective row) and then merge every single value in the vector to individual repetion of respective row. Its a question of a guy who just discovered MySQL. Or I have to do it in some programming language row by row?